# C++ it changes the value of the variable because of..?

Tags: c++, arrays, console

That is the code:

```
point [1][2][1] = 3;
cout << point[1][2][1] << endl;
point [1][3][0] = 4;
cout << point[1][2][1] << endl;
```

And that is what the console says when I run the application:

```
3
4
```

If I change to

```
point[1][3][0] = 5;
```

it says

```
3
5
```

How can I remove this annoying error? I cant continue that way.

Comment: Can you please include the declaration of `point`?

Comment: Most likely undefined behaviour (like going out of bounds).

Comment: int point[100][100][1];

Comment: If the last dimension is 1, there is no point[x][y][1]

Comment: I got it... I used 2 different ways of the 3rd dimension of this array, but I just defined 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your variable is declared as

```
int point[100][100][1];
```

Then the valid indexes are respectively `0...99`, `0...99`, `0...0`.

Your access to `point[1][2][1]` is therefore quite inappropriate.  Depending on which index you make out of range, you might access an area outside the array entirely, or in a different slice of the array.

If you really want to access array elements arbitrarily, then I suggest you discard the triple-subscript notation and use:

```
int point[m][n][p];
int* p = &point[0][0][0];
p[x*n*p + y*p + z]
```

Now you are in control over row-major vs column-major access, and any computation that yields an offset less than `m*n*p` is valid.

Note that in your case `m=n=100` and `p=1`, so that `point[1][3][0]` is `p[1*100*1 + 3*1 + 0] = p[103]` and also `point[1][2][1]` is `p[1*100*1 + 2*1 + 1] = p[103]`.  So both really are the same location.

Comment: It is rather odd to be declaring an array of length 1.